# Fastest Way to write large files

Tags: ruby, file

I have a script thats writes a series of numbers on a line  millions of times. What's the fastest way for ruby to write to a file like that?  Right now I'm calculating that it will take me about 21 hours to write 258 million lines to this file. It's also going to be roughly 8-15gigs. any suggestions ?

```
def log_file(text) 
  File.open(File.join("combo_numbers.txt"), 'a+') do |f|
    f.write("#{number}\n") 
  end
end


250000000.times do
  # math_answer =[]
  # math_answer = math 
  log_file(math_answer)
end
```

Comment: There may be a performance hit by opening and closing the file for every write.  Can you open the file once, write to it for the duration, and close it at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small logging class that only opens the file once instead of reopening it for each write

```
class Logger

  def initialize path, mode = "w"
    @path = path
    @mode = mode
  end

  def write data
    handle.write data + "\n"
  end

  private

  def handle
    @f ||= File.open(@path, @mode)
  end

  def close
    @f && @f.close
  end

end
```

Usage

```
logger = Logger.new "combo_numbers.txt"

250_000_000.times do
  logger.write "foo"
end

logger.close
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: will the file opened here close together with application?

Comment: BroiSatse: From the docs for IO#close (which File inherits from): I/O streams are automatically closed when they are claimed by the garbage collector.

Comment: @BroiSatse, bloopetech is correct, bu I added an explicit `.close` anyway

Comment: THis helped the process the time it took to write that file was just over 7hours.  I thought of Running the loops in threads as well. Since the file is written i wont have to write the file again for a while.